# Regex to match word that contains exact word

Tags: regex, nsregularexpression

I'm trying to filter specific files in Java by their names using Regex.

Idea being a lot of files are called SomethingSupport.java, AnotherSupport.java, MoreThingsSupport.java, so as they all have the "Support.java" I was trying to do:

> [Support.java]

But of course that's meant for characters so it will filter S,u,p,o, etc... Looking through RegExr I've tried:

> (Support.java)

But it takes all "Support.java" occurrences but I'm trying to take ThingsSupport.java, SomethingSupport.java, etc. not Support.java.

Comment: you can try this `\w*Support.java\b`. If you want grouping then only use `( )`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parentheses just group things. There is no difference between what regex `"Support.java"` and regex `"(Support.java)"` would match.

Note that `.` is regexpese for any character, so, e.g. `Supportxjava`, unlikely as it is that you have a file with that name in your source base, would match too. `\.` is regexpese for "an actual dot, please".

I think you're looking for the regex `.*Support.*\.java`. Which means: Absolutely anything (0 or more any character), followed by the string `Support`, followed by absolutely anything again, followed by `.java`.

That would find e.g. `FooSupportBar.java`, `Support.java`, `HelloSupport.java`, and `SupportHello.java`. It wouldn't find anything that doesn't end in `.java`.